# Why doesnt Android compress its APK's with LZ4 / LZMA?

Tags: android, 7zip, lzma, lz4

I have been doing some testing on our Unity game and it seems like we could compress the game to half its size if the APK was compressed with LZ4 instead of Zlib.

Is there a reason why Android doesnt use LZ4?

I think that iOS uses it as its roughly the same size when compressed using LZ4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simplest answer is that they haven't needed to. While LZ4 is pretty impressive, I think the Android team in order to maintain backward compatibility with older devices has chosen to leave it be. Android originally went w/ Zlib back in 2005 since they were looking for a compression algo that was widely used and didn't have any patent or license restrictions on them. That was about six years prior, to the release of LZ4 in 2011. LZMA has been around longer around 1998, has to why Android didn't use that we'll have to ask Andy Rubin himself.

Comment: Another point is that an APK is just the Java JAR format with a different suffix which in turn is the Zip file format. While additional compression algorithms have been added to the Zip format, I'm not sure if the JAR tools at the time of Android's original release would have worked correctly if the file wasn't compressed with standard Zlib.

Answer (score 2):

The most reasonable answer is because the license.
zip license from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format)):

> The .ZIP file format was released into the public domain in 1989.

Against LZMA license (from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lempel%E2%80%93Ziv%E2%80%93Markov_chain_algorithm#cite_note-LZMA_SDK-8)):

> The LZMA implementation extracted from 7-Zip is available as LZMA SDK.
>   It was originally dual-licensed under both the GNU LGPL and Common
>   Public License,[13] with an additional special exception for linked
>   binaries, but was placed by Igor Pavlov in the public domain on
>   December 2, 2008, with the release of version 4.62.

Comment: Doesnt iOS use LZMA / LZ4 tho?